# Curl not timing out properly

Tags: c++, http, curl

I have CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS = 200 and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS = 70 ms set. But my I am seeing CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME to be around 220 ms.

As per the libcurl doc, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS includes connect timeout also. So basically my curl call total time should not take more than 70 ms. But why is it taking more return back the control?

Can someone please explain this behavior.

I am using curl 7.19_02 C++ library.

Here is my code

```
CURL * curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,200);
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS,70);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); 

double tt = 0.0;
double ns = 0.0;
double ct = 0.0;
double pt = 0.0;
double st = 0.0;

curl_easy_perform(curl);

int curlRC = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &tt);
curlRC = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME, &ns);
curlRC = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME, &ct);
curlRC = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME, &pt);
curlRC = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME, &st);

cout << "Curl timing info: Total: " << tt << endl << " Lookup: "<< ns << endl << "    Connect: " << ct << "\n" << "pre transfer: " << pt << endl << "start transfer: " << st <<endl;
```

The timing info I got is as below. Please check this out

Curl timing info: Total: 0.216793

Lookup: 0.000999

Connect: 0.023199

pre transfer: 0.023213

start transfer: 0.216667

So the point is, what is happening between pre transfer and start transfer?

Comment: DNS resolution probably

Comment: Which cURL version are you using?

Comment: Can any of you guys explain, what could be the probable reason. It would be great if it can be explained by dividing the times taken for a HTTP req.

Comment: From the libcurl docs: "If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the transfer will still use full-second resolution for timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second." Perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: I checked that and thats not the reason. If 'it is built with the standard system name resolver', then it will timeout immediately if given in milli sec. But here the behavior different.

Comment: Something that occurs to me is that it is odd for the connect timeout to be greater than the total transfer timeout, and that libcurl may treat this weirdly.

What happens if you set connect timeout to be 69ms?

Comment: I tried giving lesser connect timeout/ removing connect timeout . In both the cases the behavior was identical to the above explained one.

Comment: I wanted to ask one question. When the timeout happens, why doesn't the program control return back? Since the 'start transfer' time is taking 216 ms. As per the doc, 'start transfer' is the time from start  of call till libcurl receives first byte from server. Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: why is this tagged "php" ?

Comment: One person had similar issue in php. Probably I need to remove it.

Comment: mind this from the fine manual: CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS Like CURLOPT_TIMEOUT but takes number of milliseconds instead. If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the transfer will still use full-second resolution for timeouts with a minimum timeout allowed of one second.

Comment: The program says **Operation timed out after 30 milliseconds with 953 out of 953 bytes received** when given a timeout of 30 ms. So I don't think that would be an issue. How do I confirm that anyway?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in libcurl up to version 7.20.0.
With 7.20.1 the output is like expected:

```
Curl timing info: Total: 0.071098
Lookup: 0.000116
Connect: 0.000303
pre transfer: 0.000327
start transfer: 0
```

I couldn't find the changeset fixing the bug. But could be in "sub-second timeouts improvements" in [cURL Changes](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

> So the point is, what is happening between pre transfer and start transfer?

That is the actual time the server took to calculate your result (process your request) and is ready to send the first byte of the response. In short that is the actual server time for the request and you would expect that to be the biggest piece